# Is there an app to create UML from django models?

Tags: python, django, uml

I am looking for a way to generate UML diagrams from a Django application `Model` structure.

Epydoc doesn't work with Django models because it needs django's settings.py to be imported and `manage.py   graph_models` generates unreadable output, not easily parsable and hard to convert to UML.

Is there any tool avaialble to do that?

Comment: I've started working on [app called django-spaghetti-and-meatballs that produces interactive HTML entity-relationship diagrams from django model definitions](https://github.com/LegoStormtroopr/django-spaghetti-and-meatballs/), like this i.stack.imgur.com/lvxSG.png

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django - Model graphic representation (ERD)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6776592/django-model-graphic-representation-erd)

Comment: Have you found anything better than graph_models ?

Answer (score 3):

There is a graph tool in django_extensions app. Precisely this one http://code.google.com/p/django-command-extensions/wiki/GraphModels

```
# Create a PNG image file called my_project_visualized.png with application grouping
$ ./manage.py graph_models -a -g -o my_project_visualized.png
```

Comment: -1. If you read the question, you'll noticed I talked about graph_model.

Comment: thought you didn't know about .png output

Comment: I did. When I meant unreadable, I didn't mean because of the file format, but because it's very very ugly.

Comment: When you export out as a .pdf you can search through the result for text which makes the output usable enough for me. ./manage.py graph_models -a -g -o my_project_visualized.pdf

Answer (score 1):

[pyreverse](https://www.logilab.org/blogentry/6883) which is now a part of [pylint](https://www.pylint.org/) creates reasonable UML documents.

```
pyreverse -o pdf project_name/models.py -p project
```

Comment: pyreverse analyzes general Python, not Django ORM model declarations. But `ForeignKey` (etc.) relationships in Django model classes are the most important information in what the OP was asking for.