# Django - Model graphic representation (ERD)

Tags: django, model, diagram, erd

I'm searching a way to represent my Django project model graphically.

Is there a "native" way to do this kind of [ERD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-relationship_model) (diagram) ?

---

Update following [@Etienne instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6777376/305189)

Here is an example of how I finally view the PDF representing some models of my django project

```
$ python manage.py graph_models app1 app2 ... | dot -Tpdf | evince
```

- It generates the dot data with my applications (app1, app2, ...)
- Passes the result to `dot` to output into PDF format
- Opens the output with `evince`

Comment: It's awesome to see from the one deleted answer (why has it been deleted?) a small project evolved: https://github.com/LegoStormtroopr/django-spaghetti-and-meatballs

Answer (score 106, accepted):

If you want to extract UML diagram from your Django models you can use the [Graph models](http://django-extensions.readthedocs.org/en/latest/graph_models.html) command of [django-extensions](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions). Another one that do mostly the same thing: [django-graphviz](http://code.google.com/p/django-graphviz/).

If you want to create your Django models from UML: [uml-to-django](http://code.google.com/p/uml-to-django/).

And to create UML diagrams, there's [Dia](http://projects.gnome.org/dia/), [yED](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yed_about.html) and [ArgoUML](http://argouml.tigris.org/)

You can check also this [list of tools.](http://modeling-languages.com/uml-tools/#python)

Comment: I'll use django-extension with pygraphviz ([when I succeed in installing them](http://superuser.com/questions/313278/pygraphviz-install-on-ubuntu-10-with-django-extensions):)

Comment: I just submitted a pull-request to allow use of PyDot instead of PyGraphViz; which means you won't need to worry about C extensions ;)

Comment: -1: UML is not ERD.

Comment: There is no current way to use graphviz with Python3 ATM.

Comment: @nerdoc do you mean this error: TypeError: can't use a string pattern on a bytes-like object ? That's what I'm getting on Python3.

Answer (score 6):

Best I can think of is [Argo UML](http://argouml.tigris.org/) which requires you to design by hand (and then you can convert the UML into Django with [this tool](http://code.google.com/p/uml-to-django/))

If you want to do django - uml conversion (the other way) try looking at [Django To UML](http://jaredforsyth.com/blog/2010/apr/29/django-uml/)

Comment: You can still use a tool like Argo to create your ERD diagrams. Anyway, if you have a better option, post your answer :) Just downvoting because our answers are "hacks" around a problem and not the perfect solution is a bit cocky. Cheers.

Comment: The link to Argo UML has changed to this: https://argouml-tigris-org.github.io/tigris/argouml/ and I couldn't find an updated link of Django to UML documentation.