# Model graphic representation package for Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, pip

I want ERD package which works with Python3> I tried [Django-extension](http://django-extensions.readthedocs.org/), yet, its requirement was Python2.7 and it didn't run on Python3> Does anybody know another alternative?

Comment: From the link you provided:  "At this time we test on and thrive to support valid combinations of Python 2.6, 2.7, 3.3, 3.4 and pypy with Django versions 1.4, 1.5, 1.6 and 1.7."

Comment: @MichaelC.O'Connor, Yes! until this all the things are OK, But when you want to use graph-model, you must have installed Pydot or Pygraphviz, in fact, Django-extensions is dependant to them for running this code: [`./manage.py graph_models -a -g -o my_project_visualized.png`](http://django-extensions.readthedocs.org/en/latest/graph_models.html?highlight=pydot) and they just work on Python2.7 ([Pydot](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pydot))

Comment: Nope, have you tried the development version of pygraphviz?

Comment: @ashwoods Yes! but it [doesn't also work with Python3!](http://pygraphviz.github.io/documentation/development/install.html#quick-install)

Comment: I've started working on [app called django-spaghetti-and-meatballs that produces interactive HTML entity-relationship diagrams from django model definitions](https://github.com/LegoStormtroopr/django-spaghetti-and-meatballs/), like this i.stack.imgur.com/lvxSG.png

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django - Model graphic representation (ERD)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6776592/django-model-graphic-representation-erd)