# How can I draw diagrams from database in python

Tags: python, django, django-models, modeling

How can I visually model items in a database using python?

I have a [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) project that currently models my home network in the admin views. It currently describes what devices there are and what they are connected to. For example:

```
Devices:
    Computer1
    Computer2
    Laptop1
    Mobile1
    Router1
    ROuter2

ConnectionTypes:
    Wireless24ghz
    Wireless5ghz
    cat5
    cat5e
    cat6

Connections:
    host1:
        src:Computer1
        dst:Router1
        con_type:cat5e
    trunk1:
        src:Router1
        dst:Router2
        con_type:cat6
    host2:
        src:Mobile1
        dst:Router1
        con_type:Wireless24ghz
```

The database is a bit more complex than this, however I'm keeping it simple for now as it's not that important.

What I am wondering is, how I can graphically model my network using python code to look at the database tables? By graphically model I mean something similar to a Visio diagram in that I can see it and (not necessary but a HUGE bonus) interact with it, either via webpage or application.

Are there any existing python libraries that provide this sort of functionality? I understand JavaScript is good for this kind of modelling but I'm completely unsure of how I would go about doing it.

It's worth noting I'm not after anything fancy, simply drawing devices as rectangles and connections as lines going between rectangles is good enough.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django - Model graphic representation (ERD)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6776592/django-model-graphic-representation-erd)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am pretty sure there is no ready solution for this. Look at the graphviz library and make a management command to create a DOT graph. Here is a graphviz tutorial article http://matthiaseisen.com/articles/graphviz/

Comment: Thanks, that looks like a neat tool. I don't mind writing the code for it (in fact it sounds rather fun) so that might be ideal.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're asking about Django in particular, django-extensions has already done the heavy lifting for you. Have a look at this:

http://django-extensions.readthedocs.org/en/latest/graph_models.html

Good luck!

Comment: Awesome, a nice addition to Mad Wombat's answer. I'll definitely have a look at this one, thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Django and want something simple and static, you can draw the graph into an image using the [ImageDraw module](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.0.x/reference/ImageDraw.html) offered by Pillow (the PIL replacement)
and then include that image in the web page your app delivers to the client browser.

Also, of course, you might have heard of [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/users/intro.html)

Comment: This looks like a good alternative, however it would appear to be fairly inflexible for what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: I have added a line to my answer, if it helps

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, I have been using the nwdiag library from blockdiag to create network diagrams in code.

http://blockdiag.com/en/nwdiag/

The cool thing about this is that blockdiag has lots of other useful libraries for this kind of task, such as packet and rack diagrams.