# Django - graph models relationships

Tags: django

As django project get bigger, it is hard to see all app's model relationships (ForeignKey's, ManyToMany Fields). Is there any program that can make easy looking graph of model relationship?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6776592/django-model-graphic-representation-erd

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[django extensions](http://django-extensions.readthedocs.org/en/latest/graph_models.html) has a command to do this

```
pip install django-extensions
```

settings:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'django_extensions',
)
```

run command

```
manage.py graph_models --pygraphviz -a -g -o my_project_visualized.png
```

Comment: You also need `pygraphviz` installed.

Comment: If you're on OSX: 1. `brew install graphviz`, 2. `pip install pygraphviz`, 3. `pip install django-extensions`

Comment: for ubuntu: ```apt-get install libgraphviz-dev``` was required before pip install

Answer (score 2):

First setup using this [Graphviz](https://kmonsoor.wordpress.com/2014/12/18/generate-er-diagram-from-sql-database/)

Go through **step** by **step**:

after this install graphviz or mac using

```
$ brew install graphviz
```

use this command to generate database documentation using `Schemaspy` and `graphviz`
:

```
java -jar schemaSpy_5.0.0.jar -t pgsql -db `db_name`  -host 127.0.0.1 -u `db_user` -p admin -o ./schemaspy -dp postgresql-9.4-1206-jdbc4.jar -s public -noads
```